# Explode PHP : Converting id-name to name-id to id-name

Tags: php, explode

I need some help. I have **"name"** and **"id"**, I've display is as **"id"-"name"** (suggestion) I have a function that convert it to **"name-id"** (displayed in textbox after picking the suggestion). 
The problem is, how can I properly explode if the **name = Backlink-Spider** and **id = 25**, the result 
will be **25-Backlink-Spider** and converted it to **Backlink-Spider-25** . I tend to return it to unconverted , the result is Spider-25-Backlink. 
This is my code.

```
$xpldName = explode("-", $posted['name'], 2);
          $cdata = $C->loadByName($xpldName[1]);
          $_POST['name'] = $xpldName[1]."-".$xpldName[0];
```

Comment: Only use the first item in the explode result as the ID, then join the rest back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Explode the whole string.
2. Implode all the strings except the last one
3. Print last string - imploded string

Demo Code(Not tested):

```
$xpldName = explode("-", $posted['name'], 2);    
$name     = array_slice($xpldName, 0, -1);
$name     = implode("-", $name);
$id       = end($xpldName);
echo $id . " " . $name;
```